# Sending url with parameter to action function via javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying  to open new window using window.open(actionUrl)
the actionUrl is compose form the action address and url as parameter.
so eventually the actionUrl is :
"/Default/Details?url=http://www.someaddress.com?a1=1&a2=2&a3=3"
However in the action the url i get is :
"http://www.someaddress.com?a1=1"
I do not get "&a2=2&a3=3" parameters

Here is the relevant view code:

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="test" id="btnTest" />
</div>

<script>
    var vurl = '@Url.Action("Details", "Default")';
    $(function () {
        $("#btnTest").click(function () {
            var url = "http://www.someaddress.com?a1=1&a2=2&a3=3";
            vurl = vurl + url;
            window.open(vurl);

        });
    })

</script>
```

and this is the controller and action

```
 public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    // GET: Default
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: Default/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(string url)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the encodeURIComponent function on the url parameter's value:

```
var actionUrl = '/Default/Details?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.someaddress.com?a1=1&a2=2&a3=3');
```

The `&a2=2&a3=3` part was actually part of the `/Default/Details` URL, not the `http://www.someaddress.com` one. Now that the inner URL is URI encoded, it should work.

Make sure to decode the value when using the `url` parameter though, using `decodeURIComponent`:

```
var urlMatch = location.search.match(/url=(.*)&?/);
if (urlMatch) {
    var decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(urlMatch[1]);
    // do something with the decoded URL...
}
```

**EDIT**

For the first part (URI encoding) and based on your code, you should use it this way:

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="test" id="btnTest" />
</div>

<script>
    var vurl = '@Url.Action("Details", "Default")';
    $(function () {
        $("#btnTest").click(function () {
            var url = "http://www.someaddress.com?a1=1&a2=2&a3=3";
            vurl = vurl + encodeURIComponent(url);
            window.open(vurl);

        });
    })

</script>
```

As for the ASP.NET part and the use of the `string url` parameter, I'd suggest checking the following post: [using decodeURIComponent within asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794918/using-decodeuricomponent-within-asp-net) as I'm not familiar with this environment.

Comment: Thanks,
using encodeURIComponent solve the problem.
However, i did not understand when and why to use decodeUriComponent

Comment: I guess it depends on the situation. Usually when you encode a parameter, you need to decode it when you want to use it, otherwise you end up with unwanted encoded characters. For example, the encoded `url` value is `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.someaddress.com%3Fa1%3D1%26a2%3D2%26a3%3D3` which is not a valid URL anymore. You have to decode it in order to get a valid/usable URL.But I guess ASP.NET handles URI encoded parameters natively so you don't have to bother with the decoding part